# How to mitigate the slow function in Django view

Tags: python, django

My Django website is in shared server ( nginx with uwsgi & Sqlite).

The database is huge, when users search for certain model instances, it slows down the server as it wait for the query to finish.

VIEW.PY

```
def Newssearch(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searchdata = request.POST.get('searchdata')
        result = News.objects.filter(titleEnglish__icontains=searchdata)[0:8]

    return render(request, 'newsfront/searchresult.html',{'news':result})
```

The server (Pythonanywhere.com) seems to not support async functions.

Any idea how to reduce the priority of the above function , so that if multiple types frequent requests come, it gives less priority to the search function.

Comment: There is no priority for web requests. Requests need responses when they are made. You can cache results for common searches if there are many searches that are the same or you could investigate adding indexes to your database.

Comment: If it is a free hosting then it would probably be for testing purpose and deploying static websites. You need to change to some other server like AWS it also has free tier for a year. Also i would suggest changing to some other database like mysql, postgres e.t.c they are production ready.